# Any functional difference between (*p)->some_var and *p->some_var

Tags: c

I have seen several C code examples which utilise the **(*p)**->some_var way of working with pointers (using parens around the pointer).

My question is, is there any functional difference between the two methods of working with C pointers, and if so, how did this difference come about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those do not do the same thing at all.  Compare:

```
(*p)->some_var // aka (*(*p)).some_var
```

This means "p is a pointer, which we dereference, then dereference again to access a field."

```
*p->some_var // aka *((*p).some_var)
```

This means "p is a pointer, which we dereference to access a field, which is a pointer which we dereference."

Comment: Perfect! Makes sense to me. Hard to find this info due to google not pickup the parens :)

Answer (score 3):

Since unary `*` has lower precedence than `->`, `*p->some_var` is interpreted as `*(p->some_var)`, which is obviously different from `(*p)->some_var`.

The first one dereferences the `some_var` member of the struct pointed by `p` (`p` here is something like a `some_struct *`)

```
struct some_struct {
    int *some_var;
};

some_struct *p = ...;
int v = *p->some_var;
```

The second one dereferences `p`, and accesses the `some_var` member pointed by the result (here `p` is a double pointer - `some_struct **`).

```
some_struct *a = ...;
some_struct **p = &a;
int *val_ptr = (*p)->some_var;
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at the parens and the operators:

```
(*p)->some_var
```

Or, put another way:

```
( operator* identifier ) operator-> identifier
```

Now, let's look at an [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and see what's what:

```
Precedence  Operator    Description     ...
         1  ... -> ...  Structure and union member access through pointer   
         2  ... * ...   Indirection (dereference)
```

So right there, we've got your answer:

```
(operator-with-prec-2 identifier) operator-with-prec-1 identifier
```

Do the parens make a difference? Yes. If you had `*p->somevar`, it would evaluate to `*(p->somevar)` due to the precedence of the two operators. Inserting the parens causes a change to the evaluation.

If you don't know the effect of the parens, it means you don't know the precedence and/or associativity of the operators. Print out that table and hang it on your wall - there's no shame in being a professional.

Answer (score 2):

```
(*p)->some_var
```

`p` is a pointer to a structure or union. It is dereferenced, and then its field `some_var` is accessed.

---

```
*p->some_var
```

`p` is a structure or union. Its field `some_var` is dereferenced.